# Python Xarray: how to convert a 3-d DataArray to a 2-d stacked Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have a 3d `xarray` `DataArray` volume of data of time series data for multiple runs of a model. So the rows are indexed by the simulation timestep, the columns are just a variety of variables captured about the model, and then the depth coordinate represents the individual simulation run, since I run the entire simulation multiple time.

My goal is to take this 3d `xarray` `DataArray` and convert it to a 2d `pandas` dataframe so that I can export it to a CSV file. I order to do that, I need to stack each of the simulation runs on top of each other, so that the 3d array is converted to a 2d array.

I have some code to generate some test data, but I am not familiar enough with `Xarray` to know how to do this kind of stacking.

So here is some code to develop test data.

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

results_matrix = np.zeros([5, 7, 4])
simulation_matrix = xr.DataArray(results_matrix,
                                      coords={'simdata': ['val1', 'val2','val3','val4'],
                                              'run': range(5),
                                              'year': range(7)},
                                      dims=('run', 'year', 'simdata'))

itercount = 0
for i in tqdm(range(5)):
    simulation_matrix[i, :, :] = i
    itercount += 1
```

This code will generate a DataArray that looks like

```
<xarray.DataArray (run: 5, year: 7, simdata: 4)>
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],
 ... Additional arrays truncated
```

I want this converted to a 2d `Pandas` dataframe something like

```
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.]]]
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATED:**

Based upon comments from @rahlf23 and @DSM, I had some luck with 
`simulation_matrix.to_dataframe('fred').unstack()`.

```
        fred
simdata val1    val2    val3    val4
run year                
0  0    0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   1    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   2    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   3    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   4    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   5    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   6    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   1    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   2    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   3    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   4    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   5    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   6    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: I tried that, but did not seem to work. I tried `simulation_matrix.to_dataframe().unstack()` but I get an error `cannot convert an unnamed DataArray to a DataFrame: use the ``name`` parameter` . Is the `unstack` idea the right one to use? The documentation does not show any code examples, so it is hard to tell what the commands do.

Comment: Try `simulation_matrix.iloc[:,:,1].to_pandas()`: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_pandas.html

Comment: You could just add a name to `to_dataframe`, like `.to_dataframe("fred").unstack()`, but I'm not sure I understand your expected order: I would have thought you'd want entire rows of 1s, not [1, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: You know, I just tried exactly that. But I am getting a `DeprecationWarning: 
Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.` So seems like I need to use the MultiIndex approach. Just trying to figure out how to get Multiindex to work, since I have not used that in pandas.

Comment: Right, a 3-dimensional dataframe will return a Panel, which is deprecated. That's why I would suggest reading in multiple 2D dataframes and concatenating.

Comment: Okay good. So making some progress here. I tried `simulation_matrix.to_dataframe('fred').unstack()` and that seems to do things in the right way. The problem is that it seems to leave the run number as just a single value instead of filling the column. Let me update the OP with how things look.

Comment: @krishnab: that's just the way multiindexes are represented.  You can add `.reset_index()` to confirm that they're all there.

Comment: `simulation_matrix.to_pandas().to_frame()`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. The comments got me a lot farther than I had achieved before. Thanks for the collective effort.

Answer (score 2):

Using your test data, you can use `to_pandas()` and `pd.concat()`:

```
df = pd.concat([simulation_matrix.loc[i,:,:].to_pandas() for i in range(simulation_matrix.shape[2])])
```

Yields:

```
simdata  val1  val2  val3  val4
year                           
0         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
0         1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1         1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
2         1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
3         1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
4         1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
5         1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
6         1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
0         2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
1         2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
2         2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
3         2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
4         2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
5         2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
6         2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
0         3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
1         3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
2         3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
3         3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
4         3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
5         3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
6         3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
```

Comment: Oh great. I see how you did this. Thanks so much for your help on this.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.to_dataframe` and then `unstack`, you just need to pass a name to attach to the dataset (which becomes a column containing that value):

```
In [41]: simulation_matrix.to_dataframe("results").unstack()
Out[41]: 
         results               
simdata     val1 val2 val3 val4
run year                       
0   0        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    1        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    3        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    4        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    5        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    6        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1   0        1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    1        1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    2        1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    3        1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    4        1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    5        1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    6        1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   0        2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
    1        2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
    2        2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
    3        2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
    4        2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
    5        2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
    6        2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
3   0        3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
    1        3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
    2        3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
    3        3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
    4        3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
    5        3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
    6        3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
4   0        4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
    1        4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
    2        4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
    3        4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
    4        4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
    5        4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
    6        4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

All the "run" values are there even though the default representation only shows the first in a repeated group for conciseness:

```
In [50]: df = simulation_matrix.to_dataframe("results").unstack()

In [51]: df.reset_index().head()
Out[51]: 
        run year results               
simdata             val1 val2 val3 val4
0         0    0     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1         0    1     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2         0    2     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3         0    3     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4         0    4     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks so much for the suggestion. This does get me a lot farther than I was.